# root.deiconify(), trying to pick up a minimalized app. tkinter in python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, tkinter

Part of the script responsible for minimalizing works just fine, point is, when I want to restore the window it doesnt work. I guess it's because the keyboard input is not sent into my app anymore. Can I fix that somehow? I use Ubuntu. How do I make the app wait for my shortcut no matter where in the system I am at the moment? I would like to make it work, even when I'm on my browser for example.

```py
def minimize(event):
    root.wm_state("iconic") # minimize the window

def restore_window(event):
    root.deiconify()

root.bind("<Control-z>", minimize)
root.bind("<F11>", restore_window)
```

I dont know, maybe I should use a different package than `tkinter` for that kind of software.

Comment: I have no experience with programming GUIs, but at a guess once your app has lost focus there's no way it can intercept keystrokes. So you'll need to do the keybinding for `restore` in your respective DE/WM, not the app, irrespective of your GUI framework of choice.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: You will have to use another library like `keyboard` to get the global key binding and then restore the window there